# Three.js "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined" error with object literal

Tags: javascript, three.js, object-literal

I'm trying to convert my codes to object literal style. I can create the scene but I got problems with animation.

In this line I'm getting the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined" error.

```
this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
```

This is my object:

```
var three = {
    objects: function() {
        /*objects*/
    },
    createScene: function() {
        this.container = document.getElementById("container");

        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.001, (26 * 10));
        this.camera.position.set(26, (26 / 2), 26);

        window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
            this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        });

        this.objects();

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

        this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    },
    animate: function() {
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.createScene();
        this.animate();
    }
};

three.render();
```

Comment: The value of `this` in the event listener won't be a reference to your object.

Comment: So is it not possible to animate with object literal?

Comment: It is, but you have to deal with the facts of how `this` gets its value. You could declare a variable in `createScene()` and assign `this` to it, and use that reference in the event handler.

Comment: This isn't really a threejs question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check my modified example (I borrowed your `objects` function to render a cube.. just for fun of it:) )

Basically, you need to pass the context along with your animate method using the [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
```

..what happens behind the curtain is that the first call of `this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);` happens just fine without issues because the context is passed along with `this.animate();` method. However, the second time the `animate` is called, by `requestAnimationFrame` method, the context is not there. Hence you need to pass it manually.

```js
var three = {
    objects: function() {
        /*objects*/
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 3, 3, 3 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffaa00 } );
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        this.mesh.position.set(24, 14, 12);
    this.scene.add( this.mesh );
    },
    createScene: function() {
        this.container = document.getElementById("container");

        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.001, (26 * 10));
        this.camera.position.set(26, (26 / 2), 26);

        window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
            this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }.bind(this));

        this.objects();

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    },
    animate: function() {
        this.mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    this.mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
    },
    render: function() {
        this.createScene();
        this.animate();
    }
};

three.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: There's an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'aspect' of undefined" error in the `this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;` line when changing the screen resolution. It happens in your snippets, too.

Comment: @ozgrozer Yes, because you resized the window I guess.. we have to do the same with event handler of resize window. Give me a second..

Comment: @ozgrozer I edited my answer. Notice the `.bind(this)` at the end of `window.addEventListener`.